# Reverse Singly Linked List Java, check whether circular

Tags: java, reverse, singly-linked-list, circular-list

I implemented a singly linked list in Java. I can reverse a singly linked list and check whether a given list is circular. The interesting thing is I can reverse a circular list, too which is strange and interesting. Does it make sense to be able to reverse a circular list?Actually it should get reversed over and over again right? At the moment my below code is able to reverse a circular list and terminates. Is it correct?

```
public class ListNode{
    int value;
    ListNode next;  
    public ListNode(int value, ListNode next){
        this.value = value;
        this.next = next;
    }       
    public ListNode next(){
        return next;
    }
    public void setNext(ListNode next){
        this.next = next;
    }
    public int value(){
        return value;
    }
}

public class SinglyLinkedList {

    private ListNode head;

    public SinglyLinkedList(ListNode head){
        this.head = head;
    }

    public void reverse(){
        ListNode current = head;
        head = null;
        while (current!=null){
            ListNode temp = current;
            current = current.next;
            temp.next = head;
            head = temp;
        }
    }

    public static boolean isCircular(SinglyLinkedList list){
        ListNode counter1 = list.head;
        ListNode counter2 = list.head;
        while (counter1!=null && counter2!=null){
            counter1 = counter1.next;
            counter2 = counter2.next;
            if (counter2.next!=null){
                counter2 = counter2.next;
            } else 
                return false;
            if (counter1 == counter2)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static void printSinglyLinkedList(ListNode head){
        ListNode temp = head;
        while(temp!=null){
            System.out.print(temp.value + " ");
            temp = temp.next;
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void main(String[] s){
        ListNode a4 = new ListNode(4, null);
        ListNode a3 = new ListNode(3, a4);
        ListNode a2 = new ListNode(2, a3);
        ListNode a1 = new ListNode(1, a2);
        a4.setNext(a1);

        SinglyLinkedList list1 = new SinglyLinkedList(a1);
        System.out.println(isCircular(list1));
        if (!isCircular(list1))
            printSinglyLinkedList(list1.head);
        list1.reverse();
        if (!isCircular(list1))
            printSinglyLinkedList(list1.head);




    }
}
```

Comment: Given your implementation of `reverse`, it seems strange that a circular list is reversible, as your stopping condition, that `current` is eventually `null`, should never hit in a circular list.

Comment: @MarkElliot As you can see, list1 is circular but at the same time reversible. My very first question is whether it makes sense to be able to reverse a circular singly linked list? From understanding point of view in my opinion, it makes sense to have two different directions of how I go through a list. Is my thinking correct?

Comment: I'm having problems with this too. Being able to reverse a circular list is far from strange, in fact direction of search in terms of finding or not finding, is irrelevant, that's one of the properties that identifies a circular list.

Comment: @Bob it only makes sense if the items are ordered.

Comment: @Bob, I'd be interested in seeing some output of a reversed list with loop, I suppose your head-node would be unchanged, and any path before the loop begins would also end up unchanged, but the loop itself would flip, now that I think through it...

Comment: @TonyHopkinson is my implementation wrong? I was able to reverse the list with a4.setNext(a1); omitted. It will transform 1,2,3,4 to 4,3,2,1

Comment: Without making it circular, the output is false
1 2 3 4 
4 3 2 1

Comment: @TonyHopkinson the order of the items do matter. that is why it is called a list and not a set or something.

Comment: @Bob Not my point. The reason for being able to traverse a list in either direction is in all but one case, one direction is quicker than the other.

Answer (score 0):

a4.setNext(a1);

Remove the above statement. This makes it circular.